# Nodejs, Mongodb y Promesas

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, promesas

Necesito saber cómo ejecutar Nodejs de forma correcta y ordenada lo siguiente:

> 1. Conectar con Mongo.
> 2. Ejecutar consulta (Insert, Select, Update, Delete)
> 3. Devolver resultados
> 4. Cerrar conexión.

Mi idea es que cada vez que necesite hacer una consulta, llame a la conexión, ejecute la consulta y devuelva los datos y la cierre (así tendría la posibilidad de hacer muchas consultas usando una sola conexión). Siguiendo el manual de Mongodb hice lo siguiente pero no se cómo ordenarme:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/miConeccion';
function ConectarMongo(){
var promesa = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
            if(err){
                reject(err);
                return;
            }
            resolve(db)
        });
});
return promesa;
}

var conexion = ConectarMongo();
conexion.then(
    function(db){
        return db;
    },
    function(err){
        console.log("Hemos fallado en la conexión");
    }
);
```

Comment: Y eso lo quieres hacer en un único script? o lo quieres estructurar por archivos? por ejemplo, uno de config, otro donde haces la conexión, otro de controllers donde esté el CRUD, otro de models para los schemas y así.

Comment: En realidad no. Mi primer objetivo era hacer que funcione tal cual lo pedí en la pregunta, pero dado que ya lo resolví, hice mi aplicación en capas. Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Ultimamente estoy respondiendo mis propias preguntas, bueno aquí va la solución, ya la testié:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/miConeccion";

var Conectar = function(){
return new Promise( function( resolve, reject ) {
    MongoClient.connect(url, function( err, db ) {
        if(err) reject(err);
        db.collection("usuarios").findOne({}, function(err, result){
            // console.log( result )
            resolve(result);
            db.close();
        });
    });
});
}

Conectar()
.then(function( result ) {
    console.log( result );
});
```

Mi fuente fue la siguiente respuesta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42729713/resolving-a-promise-using-mongodb-and-nodejs

Espero le sirva a alguien.